# Wherigo decompiler (for Windows)?

Tags: windows, decompiler, lua

Is there any LUA decompiler (for Windows, at best) that would work on [Wherigo](http://www.wherigo.com) cartridges?

I've tried luadec, unluac.jar and some PHP script found in Internet, but the first both fail to recognize the format, and the last just makes infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to disassemble a cartridge using [this script](http://pastebin.com/FmV8NHur).

In my case the script returned four files with jpeg extension: one empty, two valid JPEG and one which turned out to be a compiled lua script. Using unluac.jar I decoded it to a readable script.